# React and d3.js, how to ensure d3 component renders upon `.setState()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a pretty good tutorial on react + d3.js that I'm using [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-d3.js-inside-a-react-app). I simply passed data from my state to the `BarChart.js` file; I also simplified the data set to just a handful of observations and changed the x axis to quarters (instead of years). Here is the relevant code of my `app.js`:

```
  state = { 
     data: [
      {quarter: "2Q20", aum: 100},
      {quarter: "3Q20", aum: 200},
      {quarter: "4Q20", aum: 300},
      {quarter: "1Q21", aum: 400},
      {quarter: "2Q21", aum:500}
    ],
    aum:934
 }


  handleAUM = e => {
    const aum = e.target.ariaValueNow;
    this.setState({aum});


    const data = [...this.state.data];
    const index = 4;
    data[index].aum = e.target.ariaValueNow;
    this.setState({data});
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <DiscreteSlider 
               aum={this.state.aum}
               handleAUM={this.handleAUM}
            />
            <h2>USD{this.state.aum}bn</h2>
            <BarChart data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Essentially, what's supposed to happen is the user can toggle a slider which updates the value of the state. For the scope of this question, let's focus on the last item in the `data` array in the state: `{quarter: "2Q21", aum:500}`. After checking the console log, the slider is in fact updating the state -- that is to say the user can drag the slider up all the way to 2000 and the value for `aum` will be updated to that amount. See `handleAUM` function for how I'm slicing the 4th item from the data array.

In native d3, once we update the data, the svg will change too (can even add animations to make it smooth, but leaving that out for now). However, what we have here is that the state is being updated but the d3 barchart is not rendering these updates.

My understanding is that react's universal rendering of the state would sidestep these sorts of issues. Perhaps I'm not passing the props down correctly.

What's supposed to happen is the very last (right-most on x-axis) bar rect should have its height changed as the data in the props passed down to it will have different values for that time period.

### Question

Why might the bar chart not update itself automatically like we would expect in native d3 and how might I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you bind `handleAUM` method  with `this` scope in the constructor?

Comment: @Royson Sorry, not quite down with the vernacular yet, it's likely I didn't, on a hunch, not sure what that means/looks like. Will try to research.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not recognize the state change of arrays the way you do it.

Set data as a new array reference like this.

```
this.setState({data: [...data]});
```

This way, React can detect changes in array states by recognizing them as a new reference of array.

Edit:

Also, you [cannot use react hook inside of a class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20use%20Hooks,implementation%20detail%20of%20that%20component.). The article you provided shows react hook so if you were using the same code for BarChart component, it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I can see the logic in your way, but it didn't solve the issue; slider still just updates text only, not the bar chart. No errors thrown though. Not sure if it would help to see the other files for context, can check the link, my `BarChart.js` is a carbon copy of the tutorial.

Comment: The article you provided is written in react hook. Are you sure it is a carbon copy since side effects trigger differently from react class component.

Comment: I see. For sure all the bar chart files are the same. Beyond that, the only difference is that mine has an `App.js` file (which is structured as a component). If I'm not mistaken, a component can control a hook like I have attempted in the snippet (`<BarChart data={this.state.data}/>`

Comment: Is the initial state value read correctly by BartChart?

Comment: Yeah, it printed correctly in the console log, but noticed it was a string (so good idea, wouldn't have noticed that otherwise!). I cast it into an int but bar chart update behavior still not working with slider.

Comment: Also, I updated my answer to tell you that you cannot use react hook inside a class component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234600/discussion-between-kouta-nakano-and-arash-howaida).

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies in the example of `useD3` from your reference are not right. Because the `data.length` will not change so the hook `useD3` will not re-run the function used to draw the chart.

It should be:

```
useD3(() => {}, [data])
```

Comment: Where should I make this change, in usdD3.js ?

Comment: No, in your BarChart component. If the second param of useD3 is `[data.length]`, you should change it to `[data]`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you're updating `data` in `handleAUM`. When you change an attribute of an object in your data array directly, React doesn't detect a change in that item and so none of the components that depend on `data` re-render themselves.

One way to trigger a change is by replacing `data` with a new array. For example, you can use `map` to get an updated `data` array (I used the hard-coded 4th index in the ternary to match your example):

```
this.setState((state) => ({ data: state.data.map(
    (d, idx) => idx === 4 ? {...d, aum: e.target.ariaValueNow } : d
)}));
```

This way, React sees a new object for `data` in the state and re-renders the relevant components.

Here's another example that uses the data from the original tutorial you posted: https://codepen.io/kaveh/pen/rNmjjJO

This one uses `filter` on `data` to update the state. Note that `data` itself never changes and on each update, a new array from it is being set in the state.